# Whats the difference in geolocation in Cordova/HTML 5 versus the Meteor geolocation package?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, meteor, geolocation

Im trying to save a user's location when an action is done, so it wont be refreshed constantly. Also looking to do simple calculations with the stored values like distance, speed etc.

From my understanding:

**Cordova/HTML 5 geolocation** 
 1. Can set position 
 2. Asynchronous
 3. re-calibrates when a change is detected (needs watch function)
 4. Location fields - altitude, accuracy, heading fields also available
 5. Works on mobiles and html5 enabled sites (some glitches on ioS)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
// onSuccess Geolocation
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '+ position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '+ position.coords.longitude + '<br />';
}
// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
//To watch changes 
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });
```

**mdg:geolocation**
 1. No current options to set, presumable constantly reactive
 2. Easier to do calculations with the location data on the server side
 3. Works on mobile (not sure about web)

Application

```
Geolocation.currentLocation() //for getting current position 
Geolocation.latLng() //returns object with lat and lng keys
```

Are there other points or differences to be aware of Would love to hear from people who have implemented either or both and have things to say/ advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova Geolocation is very easy to use. Just use it.

> Im trying to save a user's location when an action is done, so it wont be refreshed constantly. Also looking to do simple calculations with the stored values like distance, speed etc.

Cordova doesnt consume a lot when callbacking very often `onSuccess`. I used to `return` immediatly, if conditions were not satisfied (less than 10 seconds, less than 50meter, etc.).

Cordova calls `onSuccess` as soon as geoposition has changed. Cordova is just plugged to the device geolocation layer and Cordova listens to.

**If you really want to toggle geolocation-detection, start & stop Cordova geolocation with a watchID. ** (I find it useless. But can be useful when your app goes background)

```
/*start*/
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                                      [geolocationError],
                                                      [geolocationOptions]);

    /*stops*/    
watchId=null;
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html